# XML to DataTable in C# when XML stores data in attributes

Tags: c#, xml, datatable, attributes

Is there a more elegant way to pull data from an XML file that stores its fields and data entirely in attributes?

I've been trying for over a month now to pull data from an XML file obtained via an API to turn it into a DataTable, and I am using C#, Visual Studio, and .Net classes to do so (specifically, DOMDocument60, simply because most of the examples I found were using that).

The XML file is hard to work with using any of these examples however because it stores its data not in text but in attributes. This is how all data is returned:

```
<result>
    <record>
        <field name="donor_id" id="donor_id" value="33750"/>
        <field name="first_name" id="first_name" value="Jacob"/>
        <field name="last_name" id="last_name" value="LaBay"/>
    </record>
    <record>
        <field name="donor_id" id="donor_id" value="33750"/>
        <field name="first_name" id="first_name" value="Jacob"/>
        <field name="last_name" id="last_name" value="LaBay"/>
    </record>
</result>
```

As you will see, the field name is in both "name" and "id" attributes, and the value is in "value".

My attempted methods (below) was to first obtain the columns by iterating through the entire file, looking at the "id" elements, and add them as columns to a DataTable, and ignore them if they already are a column, and then once the columns are added, to parse through all the ones with attributes of "value", and add them as rows to that DataTable. The problem is that it is inefficient (it needs to continue throughout an entire file looking for possible columns, even though it already has it at the beginning), and it is also buggy - it crashes quite frequently. So it is slow and unstable, and some large return results I can't run it all (I can enter the API string into a browser however and it looks like the problem isn't the XML, but my code that is parsing it).

The following is the code I came up with to first determine data columns, and then a method to add the rows (the object has a DataSet as a property):

```
    public void ProduceDataColumns()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        this.DataSet = new DataSet();

        IXMLDOMNodeList objNodeList;

        objNodeList = this.XMLDoc.selectNodes("//field");

        foreach (IXMLDOMNode objNode in objNodeList)
        {                
            if (objNode.nodeType == DOMNodeType.NODE_ELEMENT)
            {
                String str = objNode.attributes.getNamedItem("name").nodeValue;
                String str2 = str.Replace("_", "__");

                if (!table.Columns.Contains(str2))
                {

                    table.Columns.Add(str2);
                }
            }                             
        }
        this.DataSet.Tables.Add(table);
    }

    public void ProduceDataRows()
    {
        IXMLDOMNodeList objNodeList;

        objNodeList = this.XMLDoc.selectNodes("//record");

        int i;
        IXMLDOMNode objNode = objNodeList[0];

        for (i = 0; i < objNodeList.length; i++)
        {
            object[] array = new object[objNode.childNodes.length];
            //DataRow dataRow = new DataRow();
            int j;
            for (j = 0; j < objNode.childNodes.length; j++)
            {
                array[j] = objNodeList[i].childNodes[j].attributes.getNamedItem("value").nodeValue;
            }
            this.DataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Add(array);
        }
    }
```

If anyone could help me come up with a better way of solving this, I would be eternally grateful. I am still a bit confused about the myriad ways of parsing an XML doc that are available. Please let me know if you need more information.

UPDATE: I tried jdweng's method but it resulted in sort of a diagonal distribution of data. I feel like a foreach is missing but I've been messing with it for awhile and can't get it to work (I am still pretty confused by Linq).

Here is an image of the DataSet in a WPF DataGrid:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried just loading your XML in directly with [`DataSet.LoadXml(TextReader)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7xcc35f.aspx)  I tried with your sample XML and It Just Works, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/WivExg

Comment: `DataColumn` supports serializing from and to an XML attribute by the way, it's controlled by [`DataColumn.MappingType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.columnmapping(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I generate pivot tables all the time.  The xml you supply is not typical of a pivot table because you do not have a Key with more than one value.  Your results with the data supplied will have only one column with data for every row in the table.  A real pivot table will have one row with a key in first column (like date collected) and then multiple columns with data values.

Comment: Hi, I added a little to my XML sample to show two records being returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a start to the code using posted xml.  I think he code needs to be modified when you post better sample of xml input.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication65
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            string[] uniqueIds = doc.Descendants("field").Select(x => (string)x.Attribute("id")).Distinct().ToArray();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            foreach (string col in uniqueIds)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(col, typeof(string));
            }

            foreach (XElement record in doc.Descendants("record"))
            {
                DataRow row = dt.Rows.Add();
                foreach (XElement field in record.Elements("field"))
                {
                    row[(string)field.Attribute("id")] = (string)field.Attribute("value");
                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi JD - thank you so much! It is almost working, but I did not provide a really good XML sample, so I updated it above. I also included the output of your code, and it seems to be missing a foreach loop (I think). I am a little confused by Linq so I've been trying to edit your code to no avail. I tried adding for loops instead but that made the entire thing fall apart. Each "record" should be a row and each "field" should be a column. A new record should start a new row.

Comment: Oh my god, that worked perfectly! Thank you!!! I'm embarrassed to say I've been trying at this for the past 3+ hours, my code quadrupled in size (I was doing arrays of arrays) and wasn't even close to this. Do you have any good books you'd recommend on Linq and XML? Most of the time I look things up people are recommending Linq to XML.